# 'Take off' the country vs leave the country

Tags: verbs

I'd like to learn that Would 'taking off the country' be used instead of using 'leaving the country' in an essay. Appreciate any comment in advance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you!

Answer (score 6):

No. This sense of the "phrasal verb" verb form ***to take off*** (= **leave**) is always *intransitive* - it can't be linked to an "object", such as ***the country***, without including a preposition *(The athlete **took off from** the starting blocks like a bullet)*.

Note that the same two words can be used as a *transitive* phrasal verb (with an object, but no preposition) in, say, *The comedian **took off the Prime Minister***, where it means *made fun of, by comic parody*.